# Anime with a girl with pink hair who works in a bakery with her sister

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime seemed more directed toward kids.

The main girl, who I'm pretty sure had semi-long pink hair transforms. I believe she worked in a bakery with her sister or maybe a friend?

The bakery part is important, because I remember she has a sweet but troublesome/trickster little magical creature she was trying to catch without alerting her co-workers

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/anime-for-baking-lovers/ / https://www.cbr.com/anime-best-bakers-ranked/ one of these, perhaps?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what does she transform into? What was her name? Was this in a contemporary or fantasy setting? Was the bakery magical in some way?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What does she transform into?

Comment: One of the precures? KiraKira☆Pretty Cure A La Mode should include a Patisserie; I can't tell if it also appears in other series or not. Usami Ichika has pink hair after she transforms.